# VS breaks solution file

Tags: .net, python, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, scripting

I have a (python) **script** that accomplishes the following:

1. Scanning a folder looking for `.csproj` and `.vcproj` files.
2. Creating a solution file to contain all the projects by writing text according to the `.csproj` and `.vcproj` files.
3. Building that solution. By calling `devenv.exe /Build` from command line (`subprocess.call` on python).

My problem is: When I build, VS changes configuration in my SLN. Specifically, on SLN's `Win32` configuration, all the `.csproj` projects (.NET projects) switch from `x86` to `x64` and are marked out from the build.

Attempt that did not work: 
Changing the SLN to have all the .NETs at `x86` and the VCs on `Win32` under `x86` solution config. Again, VS breaks it when it opens the SLN : VCs are automatically change to target `x64` and marked out of the build.

Attempt that worked but quite clumsy:
First, I let VS break the file. The only clumsy way that I managed to do that is calling `/Build` then `/Clean` from command line. Next, I fix the SLN file by replacing the configs that VS broke. And now when I `/Build` it, VS does not alter the SLN.

So:

1. Anyone with a more elegant solution ?
2. Any nicer way to make VS break the file other then `/Build` - `/Clean` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is, indentation matters to the VS `sln` parser.

So folks at the company claimed it all worked back in the day, and I found it hard to believe. Over and over again I scanned the code that builds it and the sln file that is produced and couldn't tell any difference.

Beacuse I didn't look at whitespaces !

Month ago I innocently changed the code that builds the .sln file to write the file with different indentation.

Here's the difference of the files:

That worked, because the file was identical to a VS-made file, including the indenetation:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 10.00
# Visual Studio 2008
Project("{19091980-2008-4CFA-1491-04CC20D8BCF9}") = "proj1", "..\proj1_2008.vcproj", "{C844505D-3D9E-437F-94D6-BDA74999651D}"
...
EndProject
Project ...
..
EndProject
Global
Global
  GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
*good     Debug|Win32 = Debug|Win32
          Debug|x64 = Debug|x64
          Release|Win32 = Release|Win32
          Release|x64 = Release|x64
  EndGlobalSection
  ....
```

This one caused VS to re-edit, and as a side eefect to break our desired solution configuration:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 10.00
# Visual Studio 2008
Project("{19091980-2008-4CFA-1491-04CC20D8BCF9}") = "proj1", "..\proj1_2008.vcproj", "{C844505D-3D9E-437F-94D6-BDA74999651D}"
...
EndProject
Project ...
..
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
*bad    Debug|Win32 = Debug|Win32
*indent-Debug|x64 = Debug|x64
*ation  Release|Win32 = Release|Win32
        Release|x64 = Release|x64
    EndGlobalSection
    ....
```